# Modeling amp with FX Loop

Tags: amplifiers, guitar-effects, electronics, pre-amp, looping

I need a guitar amp for practicing at home.
I was considering buying Marshall Code 50 as it has a lot of effects built in and can save me some money on pedals.
However I just realized that if I will use this amp with loop pedal (and I intend to) all this fancy modeling stuff becomes redundant as this amp has no FX loop.
I wouldn't be able to play different effects in loop, it will be just playing the latest selected preset for all the loops. So eventually I will end up using this amp without any effects and buying additional pedals to use with looper.

Therefore I have two questions:

- Will modeling amp **with** FX loop behave just like I expect it to with a looper?
  Meaning, if I connect a looper to Send and Return and record the loops with built in effects, will it be played with the same effect that was recorded?
- If the answer to the previous question is YES, what are the modeling amps with FX loop that can fit my needs while still staying within the Marshall Code 50 price range out there?

Comment: If you really just want it for practicing at home, another option might be to not get an amp at all, but to get a multi-effect with built in amp sims, then plug that into the looper, then plug that into an existing stereo system (if you have one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your assumption is correct, as putting the looper between guitar and (pre)amp will only let you record the dry guitar sounds. Routing it send/return will work, as it'll pick up the sound dialled in on the amp. That means you can overdub with a different effect, and that too will stay in the loop, so to speak.

Recommendations for gear are well offside on this site, but it looks as if you need to re-think and find an amp with send/return.